# How to enable both AMQP 1.0 and AMQP 0-10 for Qpid C++ Broker 1.39.0

Tags: amqp, qpid

Qpid C++ 1.39.0 supports AMQP 1.0 and 0-10.  I would like to connect to Qpid broker using different clients that run AMQP 1.0 and 0-10.  Can Qpid broker support both versions simultaneously?  How can I turn on both protocol versions for Qpid C++ Broker?

I have tried using the "--protocols" command line option.  The value "amqp0-10" seems to work, but I could not find the value for amqp 1.0.  How can I specify both amqp 0-10 and 1.0 for the "--protocols" command line option?

Comment: Please let me know if you made any progress on this, I seem to be having a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/69073070/4224575