# Is the qpid proton API supposed to work with the qpid C++ broker?

Tags: c++, amqp, qpid, qpid-proton

I'm looking into the C++ AMQP implementations in Apache Qpid.

I've installed the [C++ broker](https://qpid.apache.org/components/cpp-broker/index.html) and I'm able to simply launch it by:

```
qpidd -p 8080
```

The obvious library choice to create client code is the [proton API](https://qpid.apache.org/proton/index.html) which has some [examples](https://github.com/apache/qpid-proton/tree/main/cpp/examples). When running the following:

```
./simple_send -a 127.0.0.1:8080
```

I get:

> amqp:connection:framing-error: Expected SASL protocol header got: Pre standard AMQP connection ['AMQP\x01\x01\x00\x0a']

When I modify the example to remove SASL from the connection options,

```
proton::connection_options co;
co.sasl_enabled(false);
```

the error becomes:

> amqp:connection:framing-error: Expected AMQP protocol header got:
> Unknown protocol ['AMQP\x01\x01\x00\x0a']

To my understanding, the proton API expects a "version 10" of the AMQP protocol and (as the error says) gets back a "1.1". Is this the case? Can I overcome this error?

`qpidd` has an option `--protocols` but I don't know how to specify the version 10 (passing strings like "AMQP 10" results in "error no protocols specified"). The broker example contained in the proton examples does work with `simple_send` but my intention is not to rewrite a broker, but use an industrial strength one, like `Qpid C++ broker`.